# Merge separate text lists alphabetically

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I need to merge the separate lists alphabetically (without the duplicates) in the same column and keep the original lists as they are.

I'd like the merged list to update automatically when one of source the list changes. Is there a formula to achieve the task without using array formula or VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, you can use:

```
=SORT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,GroupA,GroupB)&"</s></t>","//s[not (.=preceding-sibling::*)]"))
```

- create an xml using TEXTJOIN to join the two ranges
- `FILTERXML` is using an `xPath` to return a unique list of values
- `SORT` does the expected
- If you use either **Tables** or named dynamic ranges for tables A and B, the formula will autoadjust with any changes.

[image]

Comment: Instead of Filterxml, UNIQUE could be used too.